# Listing elements of factor group

Tags: group-theory

Consider the product of permutations $\sigma=(1~9~7)(8~6 ~9~ 7~ 5)(3~ 1~ 2~ 6~ 7)\in S_9$. Easily calculated by hand that $\sigma=(1~ 2~ 7~ 3~ 9)(4)(5~ 8~ 6)$. Let $G=\langle \sigma \rangle$. The order of $G$ is the order of $\sigma$ in $S_9$ which is the least common multiple of the lengths of $(1 ~2 ~7~ 3~ 9)$ and $(5 ~8~ 6)$ so
$$O(\sigma)=\text{lcm}(3,5)=15$$
Now I want to consider the factor group 
$G/H=\langle\sigma\rangle / \langle \sigma^3 \rangle$. I know that $\sigma^3$= $(1~ 2~ 7 ~3 ~9)(1 ~2~ 7 ~3~9)(1 ~2~ 7 ~3 ~9)$ since $(5~8~6)^3$ is the identity on that cycle. $\sigma^3=(1~3~2~9~7 )$ and $|H|=5$. So
$$|G/H|=\frac{|G|}{|H|}=\frac{15}{5}=3$$
Now What I'm having trouble with is listing the elements of $G/H$, how do I find  them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that the elements of $G/H$ are equivalence classes under the relation $x \sim y$ if  and only if $x = hy$ for some $h \in H$.

So let $x,y \in \langle \sigma\rangle$, then since $x = \sigma^a$  and $y=\sigma^b$ for some $a,b$ integers, we know  that $x  \sim y$ if and  only if $x = \sigma^k y$ for some $k$ which is a multiple of $3$, if and only if $a$ and $b$ differ by a multiple  of  three.  It follows that $e,\sigma,\sigma^2$ help form the three elements of the coset $G/H$, since $0,1,2$ are the  three remainders upon division by $3$.

Therefore the elements of $G/H$  are the equivalence classes  of $e, \sigma$ and  $\sigma^2$ respectively. There are  three such classes, matching with our calculation.

We would denote these elements as $H,  \sigma H$ and $\sigma^2 H$ respectively. That is, $\frac GH = \{H, \sigma H, \sigma^2 H\}$.

Comment: To add, there was no information used about  the fact that $\sigma \in S_n$ here, so this would apply in general.